# Data entered by the user are not taken into account by the parameter tree

Tags: python, parameters, pyqt, qtgui, pyqtgraph

I hope you will be able to help me and that my question will be clear enough.
I am using PyQT5 to make a GUI to configure a stage motor. In the GUI, the user can change the position etc... of the stage by changing the value in the parameter tree.
Before, there was no class MainWindow so the tree was just in the main and it worked very well (I had to create the class MainWindow to use closeEvent).

Now the user can edit the values but the change is not taken into account by the program and so the stage's parameters don't change. I don't know what I should modify in the Change function or elsewhere in order to make the transition from the main to the MainWindow class work

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()

        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):


        ######### Parameters of the Parameter tree #########
        params = [
            {'name': 'Parameters', 'type': 'group', 'children': [
                {'name': 'Center Position', 'type': 'float', 'value': CenterPos , 'step': 0.001,'siPrefix': True, 'suffix': 'm'},
                {'name': 'Range', 'type': 'float', 'value': Range, 'limits':(0,24),'step': 0.001,'siPrefix': True, 'suffix': 'm'},

                {'name': 'Step Size', 'type': 'float', 'value': StepSize,'siPrefix': True,'suffix': 'm','readonly': True},  
                {'name': 'Points', 'type': 'int', 'value': int(Points), 'limits': (1, 256), 'step': 1},
                ]},
        ]

        p = Parameter.create(name='params', type='group', children=params)

        t = ParameterTree()
        t.setParameters(p, showTop=False)
        t.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Parameter Tree')


        def change(param, changes):
            global p,StartingPoint,ArrivingPoint,CenterPos,Range,Points,StepSize
            for param, data  in changes:
                path = p.childPath(param)
                if path[0]=='Stage Parameters':
                    if path[1]=='Center Position':           
                        CenterPos = data*1E3
                        StartingPoint=data*1E3-Range/2.0
                        ArrivingPoint=data*1E3+Range/2.0
                        StepSize = (ArrivingPoint-StartingPoint)/Points
                        p.param('arameters','Step Size').setValue(StepSize)
                    if path[1]=='Range':
                        Range=data*1E3
                        StartingPoint=CenterPos-Range/2.0
                        ArrivingPoint=CenterPos+Range/2.0
                        StepSize = (ArrivingPoint-StartingPoint)/Points
                        p.param('Parameters','Step Size').setValue(StepSize)

                    if path[1]=='Points':           
                        Points=data
                        StepSize=Range/data
                        p.param('Parameters','Step Size').setValue(StepSize)
        p.sigTreeStateChanged.connect(change)
w = MainWindow()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this example code of a parameter tree : http://www.pyqtgraph.org/downloads/0.10.0/pyqtgraph-0.10.0-deb/pyqtgraph-0.10.0/examples/parametertree.py I was able to rewrite in a more proper way my parametertree. The update of the interdependent variables were achievable using a class with subfunctions like the "ComplexParameter" class of the example in the link above.

The data entered by the user are now being taken into account with the right use of global variables in the class ComplexParameter.